# iOS10: Speech recognizer is inaccurate

Tags: speech, ios10, sfspeechrecognizer

`SFSpeechRecognizer` is not accurate. I've added contextual strings. But no help. Also it is very slow in `didFinishRecognition` to be get called. `didHypothesizeTranscription` will return inaccurate text. Siri text is accurate .Please help. I'm not able to use speech to text.

Comment: Have you tried out the Apple sample project speakToMe? The recognition as in the app appears to be fairly accurate.

Comment: Yeah I have tried. It wont recognize Contextual strings provided.

Comment: Can you provide more code and tell, for example, which language you are using?

Answer (score 0):

- (void)speechRecognitionTask:(SFSpeechRecognitionTask *)task didHypothesizeTranscription:(SFTranscription *)transcription;

transcription.formattedString - this is your text

Use this method. You just wait final result.

Sorry. Type from mobile device